# Relatório de cadastro com erro no retorno do método

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver há mais de uma semana.

Desejo fazer um relatório de cadastros para um determinado site.

No relatório, quero listar as Cidades e seu total de cadastros.

Anteriormente, eu faria uma consulta sem utilizar um método, somente a  função `mysql_query()` do PHP onde eu capturaria os dados no banco MySQL, listaria os registros com o laço do tipo `while` na tela. Porém, estou querendo melhorar isso, como este sistema exige que eu utilize um método repetidas vezes, quero adequá-lo utilizando um método que sirva como um instrumento de reaproveitamento do código.

Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer o resultado que esta dentro do `while(...)` aparecer corretamente no meu método.

A estrutura do código que estou quebrando a cabeça:

```
$uf = $_POST['uf'] //aqui, $uf recebe 1 ou mais estados vai post

$x = count($uf);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $x; $i++){

    $funcao = cad_por_uf($uf[$i],$dataInicial,$dataFinal); // aqui ,passo o valor do return da funcao para a variavel $funcao;

    echo $funcao[0].'-'.$funcao[1];
}


function cad_por_uf($uf,$dataInicial,$dataFinal){

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT sum(cadastros),uf,cidade FROM tblCadastros where data >= '$dataInicial' and data <= '$dataFinal' and uf = '$uf' and deletada = 0 group by (cidade)");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $cidade = $row['cidade'];
                $cadastros= $row['sum(cadastros)'];                

                return array($cidade,$cadastros);

    }

}
```

Ao exibir a variável `$funcao[0]`, deveria listar todas as cidades do estado. Mas, ele só está me retornando **1** resultado. Como poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: use mysqli_*, o mysql_* está sendo descontinuado.

Comment: Boa tarde @IvanFerrer , eu sei hehe , ainda estou estudando php , então ainda não me aventurei com o mysql_i e o PDO.

Comment: O mysqli é mesma coisa quase, só está melhorado e mais seguro.

Comment: Sim sim , estou vendo mais o PDO , gostei mais dele . Quanto a esta situação  , o que posso fazer para funcionar ? Desde ja  grato

Comment: Você pode criar um alias:  sum(cadastros) as total, e recuperá-lo `$row['total']`.

Comment: Além disso, a palavra `data` é reservada no MySQL, sugiro que vc substitua por "data_reg".

Comment: Boa tarde , na verdade esta como 'data_cadastro' hehe . Vou tentar a sugestão do @rray  , e posto aqui como ficou .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retorne todas as linhas após o while não precisa criar um array novo, use uma alias para o calculo.

```
function cad_por_uf($uf,$dataInicial,$dataFinal, $conexao){
    $consulta = "SELECT sum(cadastros) as cadastros, uf, cidade
                 FROM tblCadastros
                 WHERE data >= '$dataInicial' and data <= '$dataFinal' and uf = '$uf' and deletada = 0 group by (cidade)";

    $sql = mysql_query($consulta, $conexao);
    $lista = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $lista[] = $row;
    }
    return $lista;
}
```

Comment: boa tarde @rray , vou testar aqui e ja posto se deu certo .

Comment: Qual o problema com a resposta?

Comment: Boa tarde,  deu certo aqui ! O unico problema que teve , foi que tipo, quando do o print na variavel $funcao[numero array] , ele retorna , [0] => 0 , [cadastros] => 0 , [1] => SP , [uf] => SP , [2] => sao paulo , [ cidade] => sao paulo ) etc etc .  Não entendi por que ele retorna um array numerico e depois o array com o nome do campo do banco de dados.  Por que  ele retorna assim ?

Comment: @HenriqueFelix, vc quer o retorno como?

Comment: Se possivel , que retornasse no array , o nome do campo do banco e o valor dele  , tipo , ([cadastros] => 0 ; [uf] => SP , etc )

Answer (score 1):

O correto neste caso seria fazer sua query desta maneira:

**Obs:** troquei ***data*** para ***data_cadastro***, pois data é uma palavra reservada do *MySQL* e por isso retornará com erro. Outro detalhe é a forma de declarar array. Você declara de duas formas: `$array = [];` (versão 4.5 ou superior) ou `$array = array();`. Outra coisa é não faz sentido passar a conexão para dentro do método da `mysql_query()`. Adequei o método com o padrão PSR-1 e PSR-2.

```
function cadPorUf($uf, $initialDate, $finalDate)
{

   $sql = "SELECT sum(cadastros) as total,
           uf,
           cidade FROM tblCadastros
           WHERE data_cadastro
           BETWEEN '$initialDate' and '$finalDate'
           AND uf = '$uf'
           AND deletada = 0
           GROUP BY cidade";
    //faça um upgrade para PDO (vamos colaborar para melhorar e não piorar os códigos)
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $list = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Se for uma função faz sentido sim passar a conexão, todas as variáveis globlais são acessiveis dentro de funções?

Comment: Então  , eu nao estava passando a $conexao  ,e ainda sim estava funcionado.O correto seria passar ela mesmo assim ?

Comment: @HenriqueFelix é uma classe ou só uma função?

Comment: @rray , é somente uma função.Chamo a pagina que faz a conexao na minha controller.php. E na pagina controller.php  , faço o include das demais paginas do site .

Comment: Aproveitando ,o resultado de ambos deu certo , mas estou usando o _fetch_assoc , pois o array retornou mais amigavel. :                                     Array                                                                                                            ( [0] => Array ( [sum(cadastros)] => 1 [uf] => SP [cidade] => Itapeva )                                       [1] => Array ( [sum(cadastros)] => 1 [uf] => SP [cidade] => ALTAIR )                 [2] => Array ( [sum(cadastros)] => 1 [uf] => SP [cidade] => alto alegra ) etc etc

Comment: a diferença entre ..._fetch_array e ..fetch_assoc, é que array, vc pode usar tanto indice numérico como chave associativa, já o ...fetch_assoc, vc é obrigado a capturar pela chave associativa.

Comment: Vish , realmente não sabia disso,  e nesse caso ,o fetch_assoc cai melhor mesmo , por que assim , ao exibir o array , ele só mostra os campos do banco e nao o indice e depois o nome do campo .

Comment: se vc fizer isso, já resolve o problema: `mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Comment: a palavra conexão ali não está sendo usada. Só pra avisar...